# Laravel with ajax vanila javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

i´m new use laravel, i´m try create an app of contacts to practice.

How i can call the url or route the controller with javascript?, show my code for to explain me. I´m create new method in the controller contacts called insertDate. I´m call this method in the view save.blade.php and use the ajax in principal template navs.blade.php this document is inside to folder layouts, the script the javascript is inside of folder public js/ajax.js.

The console navigator, print an error 404 not found POST, is with the script url, how i can call the url of my controller or route?

Web.php

```
//Routes 
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('contactos', 'Contacts');

Route::post('contactos', 'Contacts@insertDate')->name('contacts.insertDate');
```

Contacts Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contact;

class Contacts extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){

        //$this->middleware('auth');

    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
        //
        $ejemplo = 'Prueba';
        $hola = 'pepito es pepa';
        return view('save', compact('ejemplo', 'hola'));
    }

    public function insertDate(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $contact = new Contact;
            $contact->name = $request->name;
            $contact->phone = $request->phone;
            $contact->save();

        }



    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Save Blade

```
<div class="container-form">
    <form action="{{ route('contacts.insertDate')}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control-sm inputs" placeholder="Persona">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control-sm inputs" placeholder="Celular">
            <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

ajax

```
let name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
let phone = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
let save = document.querySelector('#save');
let getUrl = "{{ route('contactos') }}";

const saveDate = ( url, var1, var2) =>{
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    let token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    let data = {
        _token: token,
        name: var1,
        phone: var2
    }
    xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(data);
}

save.addEventListener('click', saveDate(getUrl, name, phone));
```

The console navigator, print an error 404 not found POST, is with the script url, how i can call the url of my controller or route?

Comment: there is no `route('contactos')` which has name of `contactos` ,i guess your getUrl should be `{{ route('contacts.insertDate') }}`

Comment: hi Muhammad Amirozzaman Niaz, thanks but the console browser print this error ajax.js:16 POST http://contactos.test/%7B%7B%20route('contacts.insertDate')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: `{{ route('contacts.insertDate') }}` should be return a Url, not itself. As this was a blade syntax,it must be in blade.php file to render with a url.

Comment: Try to insert hard coded url in `getUrl` for test purpose that your request was successful.

Comment: mmm a example please, i have this script inside the template nav.blade.php, i remove the code script src="{{ asset('js/ajax.js')}} and add @yield('script') in the template view, before add the script in the view save @section script  , but i cant resolve this problem :/, Can you help me with one example?

Comment: Is it give you same error?

Comment: Muhammad Amirozzaman Niaz i change the code of javascript, was {{ route('contacts.insertDate')}} now is let getUrl = document.forms.createContact; let urls = getUrl.getAttribute('action') and the console browser print ajax.js:17 POST http://contactos.test/contactos 419 (unknown status)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one in your `blade`

```
<div class="container-form">
<form action="{{ route('contacts.insertDate')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control-sm inputs" placeholder="Persona">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control-sm inputs" placeholder="Celular">
        <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
        <input id="url" value={{ route('contacts.insertDate') }} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    </form>
</div>
```

And `ajax`

```
let name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
let phone = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
let save = document.querySelector('#save');
let getUrl = document.querySelector('#url').value;

const saveDate = ( url, var1, var2) =>{
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    let token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    let data = {
        _token: token,
        name: var1,
        phone: var2
    }
    xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(data);
}

save.addEventListener('click', saveDate(getUrl, name, phone));
```

Comment: Muhammad Amirozzaman the console browser print this error ajax.js:17 POST http://contactos.test/contactos 419 (unknown status), i´m search this error and results with is token.

Comment: edit your controller, everything comment out,only `return 'success'`

Comment: 419 return for CSRF Protection,is it set so,check it.

Comment: I edit the controller inside of if($request->ajax()){ return 'success'; } and change code javascript let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');;    and the console print the same error 419

Comment: i dont remove nothing, i put return 'success'; as you told me e.e, but i have the error 419 ajax.js:17 POST http://contactos.test/contactos 419 (unknown status), Do i use wrong token in the javascript?

Comment: sorry,i have no clue...might be your token was not placed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad Amirozzaman Niaz thanks, i got the answer, need put setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]'))

ajax

```
let name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
let phone = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
let save = document.querySelector('#save');
let getUrl = document.forms.createContact;
let urls = getUrl.getAttribute('action')

const saveDate = ( url, var1, var2) =>{
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');;
    let data = {
        _token: token,
        name: var1,
        phone: var2
    }
    xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
    xhttp.send(data);
}

save.addEventListener('click', saveDate(urls, name, phone));
```

View Save Blade

```
@extends('layouts.nav')


@section('content')
   <style>
       .container-form{
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           margin-top: 25px;
       }
       .table-insert{
           margin-top:25px;
       }
   </style>

    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">Welcome to Contact App</h2>
        <h4 class="text-center">{{-- auth()->user()->name --}}</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="container-form">
    <form action="{{ route('contacts.insertDate')}}" method="POST" name="createContact">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control-sm inputs" placeholder="Persona">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control-sm inputs" placeholder="Celular">
            <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
     </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container table-insert">

    </div>

@endsection

@section('script')
<script src="{{ asset('js/ajax.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Controller Contact

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contact;

class Contacts extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){

        //$this->middleware('auth');

    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
        //
        $ejemplo = 'Prueba';
        $hola = 'pepito es pepa';
        return view('save', compact('ejemplo', 'hola'));
    }

    public function insertDate(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $contact = new Contact;
            $contact->name = $request->name;
            $contact->phone = $request->phone;
            $contact->save();
            return 'success';
        }



    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: good job, is it `$request->ajax()` give you correct info?i was tried with it,not found useful.

Comment: Sorry to answer now, but in venezuela the light is gone are one hour, i´m using $request->ajax() and the browser response with status 200, but not insert the infomation in database :( Have you a red social for talk more fluid?